# I am getting this error ,"value for message cannot be cast from double to string"

Tags: react-native

> I am getting this error when I am trying pass object to axios method "value for message cannot be cast from double to string". Does any one have Idea about this.
>
> I have added my two functions.

```
  addNotes = (formData) => {
    let noteText = ''
    Object.keys(formData).map((item) => {
        noteText += formData[item] !== undefined ? `${formData[item]} \n` : ``
    })
    let localLocation = `${this.state.localAddress.locality}, ${this.state.localAddress.subLocality}`
    let { userMetaData, graphListlimit, graphListoffset, imdCode } = this.state
    let obj = {
        'edEmployeeCode': userMetaData.ed_employee_code,
        'edName': userMetaData.ed_name,
        'edRoleCode': userMetaData.ed_role_code,
        'imdCode': imdCode,
        'imdSegment': null,
        'bnNoteText': noteText,
        'location': localLocation,
        'meetingType': this.state.meetingType
    }
    this.props.onAddNotesAction(obj)
}


export const addNotesAction = (obj) => {
 let params = {
    ed_employee_code: obj.empCode,
    ed_role_code: obj.empRoleCode,
    ed_channel: obj.empChannel,
    ed_name: obj.edName,
    imd_code: obj.imdCode,
    imd_segment: null,
    bn_note_text: obj.bnNoteText,
    location: obj.location,
    meeting_type: obj.meetingType
}
return dispatch => {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = obj.token;
    axios.post(`${Config.apiRootPath}/meetings/addbranchnote`,
        params,
    ).then(response => {
        dispatch(addNotesSuccess(response));
    }).catch(err => {
        dispatch(addNotesFailure(err.response));
    });
};
```

};

Comment: Can you post some code snippet?

Comment: @AadityaThakkar I have add code.

Comment: @vichal I think this issue is with obj.token you passed in axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']

Comment: @ShashinBhayani I have checked that as well without token it's throwing an error which is valid ,its not relate with token

Comment: Are you passing the object that you create in `addNotes` to `addNotesAction` because if so some of the property names don’t match and there seems to be one missing?